# convert decimal to binary

Tags: java, binary

Code is mostly done but my code is printing incorrectly its printing out as 110 as opposed to 011. The problem im doing requires to reverse the "110" to "011"

```
import java.util.Scanner; 

public class LabProgram {   
    public static void main(String[] args) { 

Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);


   int num, binaryNum = 0;
   int i = 1, rem;

   num = scan.nextInt();

   while (num != 0)
   {
      rem = num % 2;
      num /= 2;
      binaryNum += rem * i;
      i *= 10;
   }


 System.out.println(binaryNum);
}
}
```

Comment: the maximum number an integer can take is 2147483647. That's only 10 digits, meaning the maximum binary number you can have is 1111111111, which is 1023. You should use a String instead to store your binaryNum if your input is going to be greater than 1023

Comment: Your code is working correctly.  If you put in 6 it prints 110 which is correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Then use a string as follows:

```
   int num = scan.nextInt();

   String s = "";
   while (num != 0) {
    int   rem = num % 2;
      num /= 2;
      s = s + rem; // this concatenates the digit to the string in reverse order.

      // if you want it in normal order, do it ->  s = rem + s;
   }
   System.out.println(s);
```

Comment: Or if OP wants no strings, `binaryNum = (binaryNum * 10) + rem`..?

Comment: @ashu for regular binary numbers, yes.  But it doesn't show the leading zero if printed backwards, it shows 11 for 6 and not 011.

Comment: Aah yes! _Off by zero_ :p

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use Integer#toBinaryString(int) to return the result as a binary string.

```java
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

        int value = scan.nextInt();

        System.out.println(Integer.toBinaryString(value));
```

Comment: im pretty new to java so im not sure how to do that :P

Comment: Updated the main post.

Comment: Updated post as I misspoke.

Answer (score 0):

You may directly print each binary digit without storing it in `binaryNum`

```java
while (num != 0) {
    System.out.print(num % 2);
    num /= 2;
}

System.out.println();
```