# Convert from decimal to binary Java error

Tags: java, binary

I'm writing a simple Java program to convert from decimal to binary.

```
public static int toBinary(int n) {
    int result = 0;

    while (n >= 1) {
        int power = 0;

        while ((int) Math.pow(2, power) <= n) {
            power++;
        }

        result += (int) Math.pow(10, power - 1);
        n = n - (int) Math.pow(2, power - 1);
    }

    return result;
}
```

The program works for n up until 1023, but fails after that and I'm not sure where I did wrong. Can someone help?

Comment: Could you perhaps elaborate on „fails after that“. This is not very expressive...

Comment: `Ints` are already in binary.  What you want is the binary representation of a decimal number.  So just use `Integer.toBinaryString()`.  If you grow your own, store the result in a String, not an int.  Here is one [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60552499/convert-decimal-to-binary/60552661#60552661) of how to do it.

Comment: May I suggest using a Bitset to store the result of your conversion?

Answer (score 1):

Your code has a problem of [`Integer Overflow`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integer_overflow).

Binary of `1024` is `10,000,000,000` and the max value an `int` can hold is `2,147,483,647`.

Use an int array to store the number:

```
public static void convertBinary(int num) {
    int[] binary = new int[40];
    int index = 0;
    while (num > 0) {
        binary[index++] = num % 2;
        num /= 2;
    }
    for (int i = index - 1; i >= 0; i--){
        System.out.print(binary[i]);
    }
}
```

---

You can also use the [in-built](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#toBinaryString(int)) method.

```
System.out.println(Integer.toBinaryString(1024));
```

---

You can also use `StringBuilder` to store the result:

```
public static void convertBinary(int num){
    StringBuilder binary = new StringBuilder();
    while (num > 0){
        binary.append(num % 2);
        num = num / 2;
    }
    System.out.println(binary.reverse());
}
```

Do not use `String` (immutable) in a loop, always use a `StringBuilder` (mutable).

Comment: If you're going to tell the OP how to do it then don't use an array.  Use a StringBuilder or  just a String.